# LinkedIn Oauth2.0 Django login using Python-social-auth, invalid redirect URI

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-social-auth

I'm trying to add "Login via LinkedIn" functionality in my website.
My Django project name is "botdjango" and app name is "botgetdata".

These are the steps I followed-

```
pip install social-auth-app-django
```

Made these changes in "settings.py"

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'botgetdata',
'social_django',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',]

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
            'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
        ],
    },
},
]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'social.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = 'my_key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET ='my_secret'
```

Made migrations using-

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This is my "urls.py" -

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^', include('botgetdata.urls')),
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
url(r'^oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')), 
]

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'
```

This the code for login button on webpage:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'linkedin-oauth2' %}">Login with LinkedIn</a><br>
```

I'm attaching the screenshots of login page and the error I'm getting.[Login Page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DccTJ.png)  [Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu7qq.png)

These are the callback/redirect URL's I have tried on LinkedIn-

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/linkedin-oauth2/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/sociall-auth/complete/linkedin-oauth2/
http://localhost:8000/login/linkedin-oauth2/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/linkedin-oauth2/
```

I have gone through many questions already posted here on StackOverflow but could not resolve this issue. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: You are adding `social auth` under `oauth/` path, then your redirect uri should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/complete/linkedin-oauth2/`.

Comment: @omab Thanks! It worked like charm! I really can not thank you enough... I was stuck in this for a very long time!

Comment: Glad it helped!